# Error parsing data from XML python "NameError: name 'XXX' is not defined"

Tags: python, xml, parsing

Code: 
Parsing some data from an XML file as , taking user input and trying to replace a sub-string in the text parsed from the XML file.
(This is for a upcoming HID attack framework https://github.com/SkiddieTech/HIDAAF, part of my offensive computer security degree)

```
def Generate_Payload(payload):
      print " Selection : " , payload
      import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
      payload_raw = ET.parse(payload).getroot().find('payload').text                
      print payload_raw
      shell_name = input("Please enter the name of your malicious apk :")                   
      payload_raw_filtered = payload_raw.replace('#APKNAME#', shell_name)                   
      print payload_raw_filtered
      os.system('pause')
```

Error:

```
           Please enter the name of your malsivus apk :apk
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:\Users\Master\Documents\GitHub\HIDAAF\hidaaf.py", line 52, in <module>
                List_Payloads()
              File "C:\Users\Master\Documents\GitHub\HIDAAF\hidaaf.py", line 41, in List_Payloads
                Generate_Payload(filenames[payload - 1 ])
              File "C:\Users\Master\Documents\GitHub\HIDAAF\hidaaf.py", line 18, in Generate_Payload
                shell_name= input("Please enter the name of your malicious apk :")
              File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
            NameError: name 'apk' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using python 2. Use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

`input` is for entering actual python code, so it's complaining that the variable with name `apk` is not defined.

This is not the case in python 3.

Comment: Thank you! Is the current Phy2 already outdate? Should i be porting this to Phy3?

Comment: Yes. Use python 3 so your code will be relevant in 2 years.

Comment: FYI: Python 2 is EOL in 2020 and will no longer be maintained.